# Momentum of projectile in the centre of mass frame in a two body system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, scattering

The COM frame is defined as the coordinate system in which the centre of mass of the system is at rest. In the case of a 2-body system the center of mass coordinate is:
$$\vec{R_{CM}} =  \frac{M_A \vec{R_A} + M_B \vec{R_B}}{M_A + M_B}$$

And the velocity of the COM is:

$$\vec{U_{CM}} =  \frac{M_A \vec{U_A} + M_B \vec{U_B}}{M_A + M_B}$$

Now my book affirms that momentum of the projectile particle $A$ ($B$ is at rest in laboratory frame) is related by the following:
$$\vec{p_A} = \vec{q_A} - M_A \vec{V_{CM}}$$

where $\vec{q_A}$ is the momentum of particle $A$ in the laboratory frame and $\vec{V_{CM}}$ is the velocity of the COM (in the laboratory frame). How does this result follow?

Comment: $p_A=m_A(V_A-V_{CM})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivation was quite easy, I just got a bit confused. I just had to use the transformation between velocities: $\vec{U} = (\vec{U})_L - \vec{V_{CM}}$
$$\vec{p_A} = M_A (\vec{U_A}) = M_A ((\vec{U_A})_L - \vec{V_{CM}}) = \vec{q_{A}} - M_A \vec{V_{CM}}$$